# Remote scheduled Screenshot

Tags: powershell, screenshot

I want to make a scheduled task so I can make a screenshot o a website every hour for monitoring purposes. I am using the following powershell script:

---

```
#Open website
start https://nu.nl

#wait
Sleep -Seconds 5

#make screenshot
$File = "C:\Temp\Screenshot1.bmp"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Gather Screen resolution information
$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left = $Screen.Left
$Top = $Screen.Top

# Set bounds
$bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $Width, $Height

# Create Object
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)

# Capture
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)

# Save
$bitmap.Save($File)
```

---

We use a automation tool to execute the script but I am getting an error while running it:
Exception calling "CopyFromScreen" with "5" argument(s): "The handle is invalid"

Someone an Idea to resolve this?

When I try this local I have no issue but I'm not able to do it with the automation tool

Comment: Does the automation tool run it from a service / in the services session?

Comment: See c# example which uses THIS.  You need the form which contains a handle : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.8&force_isolation=true  You need a new-object for the form.

Comment: It is running as a service but I think I need to fix this with C#.